# AJAX progress bar on array iteration?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am not too familiar with AJAX but I'm sure what I am trying to do is possible.

Basically I have a form with a text area, when the form is submitted the text area is made into an array with each new line being a value. Simple stuff, now my php then performs a database query on each array value. Also simple.

Now as the operation takes a while I want to make it into an AJAX call using jquery, and for every iteration on the array I want it to display the result back on my main page as well as displaying a progress bar.

So if my text area contains a list of 20,000 names and the query is to fetch the ages of these people, the ajax call would split the textarea into an array and iterate the array. For each iteration it should perform the query and send the result to my main page. So on my main page I will see a list that grows over time.

I hope I have explained this well enough, I just need advice on where to start/what to research. Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: [A simple fiddle that might help](http://jsfiddle.net/6ym3S/15/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ajax is simply a request for data you cannot create a reliable loading bar easily.

However if you are doing loads of requests as you suggest in your question, "Which by the way is not the best idea".

You could do something like the code below. Again its pretty basic but will give your user a rough idea. I stuck it in a fidddle here for you http://jsfiddle.net/6dgAF/ its a basic example but should give you a jump off point.

```
function Status(data)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.size = this.data.length;
    this.current = 0;
    this.bar = $("#bar");
    //Get width of each step of load
    this.step = (this.bar.width() / this.size) ;
    for(var i =0; i < this.size; i++){
     this.getData(this.data[i]);   
    }

}
Status.prototype.getData = function(string){
    //run your ajax here on each string and on success do this

    //$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( string ) {
         //this.current++;
          //this.updateBar();
        //});
    this.current++;
    this.updateBar();
}
Status.prototype.updateBar = function(){
    //updates the bar with the current count * step width;
    $("span",this.bar).width(this.step*this.current);
}

//Init object and put in dummy data
var status = new Status(new Array("string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6","string7","string8","string9","string10"));
```

Answer (score 0):

An AJAX request is nothing else than requesting data from your server, just like any HTML page. The only difference is that you use Javascript, and don't feed the data to your browser as an HTML page, but use the data some way *on* your page.

One possible way to do the thing you want is the following:

- Set an interval with the refresh rate, which calls a function `getData`
- In `getData` you perform an AJAX request, which requests a piece of data from the server, which represents the current state. You might want to make sure the server only returns incremental updates, to avoid sending large amounts of data
- Use the data on your front page, by displaying it in a friendly way to the user.

The main thing to keep in mind is that the server must save it's current state (the data which it has gathered with its queries), which it must return in the event of an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called **XHR2** - personally I am using dojo 
(dojo/request/xhr here)

However it should be possible with jQuery as well, search for jQuery XHR2 progress ...